# How can I find out what my domain is for connecting with samba?

Tags: samba

I am attempting to mount a password protected network share from a NAS unit that works by appearing as a windows share. On Windows, I just Map Network Drive, and enter in `\\x.x.x.x\ShareName`, then enter a password at the prompt.

On my Linux system, when I attempt to open `smb://x.x.x.x/ServerName`, I get a prompt for password **and domain**. As far as I know, since my share is set up as a workgroup, I do not have a domain. What should I enter here or do to mount this share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answerer provided the right answer yesterday but deleted it, which I only saw in my inbox, so I can't tell who they are. The correct answer was to use the hostname of the NAS unit as the domain.